# ClickOnce publish previous application

Tags: .net, clickonce, updates, versioning, rollback

I have checked quite a lot of articles about reverting **ClickOnce** applications to previous version, but most of them apply to users' local environment.

I have an **Application 1.0** which is published and installed on my local machine. 
No I publish an **Application 2.0** and running it from my local machine causes the  update. Now I realize that this version has some serious issues and we have to revert to **Application 1.0**.

In every article I have seen it is to publish **Application 1.0** files with increment vesion of ClickOnce packet (e.g. **Application 3.0** but with binaries of **Application 1.0**).

I run some testing with different approach. I just simply published **Application 1.0**. Once I try to run **Application 2.0** from my local machine system asks me if I want to update the version. When I agree to that **Application 1.0** is downloaded and run. Moreover if I had at any time **Application 1.0** on my machine it can start without downloading files because ClickOnce can cache it.

This can prove that version does not necessarily has to be incremented but changed (decremented too). I am aware that there may be some problems when you publish decremented version with different binaries, but assume we want to revert to previous version of binaries.

Can you tell me if this is how the ClickOnce mechanisms are designed or I am doing something against its principles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the old version to the publish location is exactly the way we replace flawed versions of an application. Although I'm not sure if this is against the principles of ClickOnce, I can confirm that it works.